# Selecting the first record in a "group"

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by, partitioning

I'm in the process of writing a Sequel Server 2008 query to pull data that will allow me to make alumni cards that have an "alumni since" field.   I've gotten my query to pull all of their course records -- now I want to narrow it down to only include the oldest course.

My code so far is listed below.

I've looked online and tried the whole row partition thing as well as the using the whole min/max with groups, but I haven't had much success with it.  The only unique value in this is the UserID -- the CourseID is essentially a shorthand for the course name (each of which are offered several times a year).  All of the similar examples I've seen on here don't have any WHERE clauses to pull that initial data set, so I'm not sure where they go.

Any help or suggestions would be very very welcome!

```
SELECT
    DisplayName, UserID, CourseID, EndDate
FROM
    BigTable
WHERE
    SIMPLE WHERE CLAUSE 1
    AND SIMPLE WHERE CLAUSE 2
    AND SIMPLE WHERE CLAUSE 3
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, EndDate ASC
```

Generates this:

```
DisplayName    UserID  CourseID   EndDate
-------------|--------|--------|------------------------
John Doe     | 123579 |  DPRM  | 2000-09-29 00:00:00.000
Mother Goose | 121157 |  ICCT  | 2009-06-19 00:00:00.000
Boy Horner   | 117223 |  ICCT  | 2003-11-21 00:00:00.000
Boy Horner   | 117223 |  DPRM  | 2008-06-20 00:00:00.000
Miss Muffett | 115280 |  SDPB  | 2006-11-03 00:00:00.000
Simple Simon | 190423 |  SDPB  | 2013-10-11 00:00:00.000
Jack Sprat   | 115868 |  SDPA  | 2005-11-04 00:00:00.000
Jack Sprat   | 115868 |  SSTR  | 2008-11-07 00:00:00.000
```

The kind of output I'm expecting would look something like this (just one line per person with their oldest enddate)

```
DisplayName    UserID  CourseID   EndDate
-------------|--------|--------|------------------------
John Doe     | 123579 |  DPRM  | 2000-09-29 00:00:00.000
Mother Goose | 121157 |  ICCT  | 2009-06-19 00:00:00.000
Boy Horner   | 117223 |  ICCT  | 2003-11-21 00:00:00.000
Miss Muffett | 115280 |  SDPB  | 2006-11-03 00:00:00.000
Simple Simon | 190423 |  SDPB  | 2013-10-11 00:00:00.000
Jack Sprat   | 115868 |  SDPA  | 2005-11-04 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) with a [`CTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DisplayName, UserID, CourseID, EndDate,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY EndDate ASC)  
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT DisplayName, UserID, CourseID, EndDate
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/acb51/3/0)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you thank you!!  I figured out that I just needed to add my where clause operands to pull the initial row (they go right under the first FROM statement)